# Tkinter dynamic color ranges

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I'm telling each line exactly what it's background and foreground color will be based on it's age.

input

```
        for i in range(0, 9999):
            if i == i:
                z = i + 2
                z = z + float(0.20)
                z = str(z) + "0"
                a = i + 2
                a = a + float(0.36)
                if past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 56: # 56 days
                    txt1.tag_add("red_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 28: # 28 days
                    txt1.tag_add("red4000_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 14: # 14 days
                    txt1.tag_add("orange_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 7: # 7 days
                    txt1.tag_add("orange_yellow_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 5: # 5 days
                    txt1.tag_add("yellow_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 1: # 1 day
                    txt1.tag_add("lime_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 22: # 22 hours
                    txt1.tag_add("light_green_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 60 * 60 * 2: # 2 hours
                    txt1.tag_add("neon_green_line0", z, a)
                elif past_list[i] >= 0: # 0 hours
                    txt1.tag_add("blue_line0", z, a)
    except IndexError:
            pass
    txt1.tag_config("blue_line0", background="black", foreground="#0000ff")
    txt1.tag_config("neon_green_line0", background="black", foreground="#39ff14")
    txt1.tag_config("light_green_line0", background="black", foreground="#90ee90")
    txt1.tag_config("lime_line0", background="black", foreground="#bfff00")
    txt1.tag_config("yellow_line0", background="black", foreground="#ffff00")
    txt1.tag_config("orange_yellow_line0", background="black", foreground="#f8d568")
    txt1.tag_config("orange_line0", background="black", foreground="#FFA500")
    txt1.tag_config("red4000_line0", background="black", foreground="#FF4000")
    txt1.tag_config("red_line0", background="black", foreground="#FF0000")
```

It displays it all correctly, something very new is blue, then it becomes green, and so on.
I was just wondering if there was a way to make it more efficient, as in, if something is designated blue at 0 seconds, and green at 60 seconds, can it display at half green half blue at the 30 second mark? Only because it's transitioning from blue to green as the seconds tick by.
Hope that made sense.

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. You can update the colors to whatever you want as time passes. Is that all you're asking?

Comment: No, was asking if there's some kind of module or technique that makes it easier?

Comment: No, there is nothing in tkinter to make this easier than directly changing the colors yourself whenever you want.